# How do I use the `fetch()` function in React Native to retrieve posts from WordPress REST API?

Tags: wordpress, react-native, fetch-api, wordpress-rest-api, create-react-native-app

I'm using the create-react-app to build an React Native app that would show a list posts from WordPress. I have a problem fetching the data from WordPress. I think I'm not fully understanding how the `fetch()` function works.
This is what I have at the moment:

```
export default class Posts extends Component {
  constructor() {
    super();
    this.state = {
      posts: []
    }
  }
componentDidMount() {
    let dataURL = "http://localhost/wordpress/wp-json/wp/v2/posts";
    fetch(dataURL)
      .then(response => response.json())
      .then(response => {
        this.setState({
          posts: response
        })
      })
  }
render() {
    let posts = this.state.posts.map((post, index) => {
      return
      <View key={index}>
      <Text>Title: {post.title.rendered}</Text>
      </View>
    });
return (
      <View>
        <Text>List Of Posts</Text>
        <Text>{posts}</Text>
      </View>
     )
  }
}
```

This is the warning that I get:

> Possible Unhandled Promise Rejection (id:0)
> TypeError: Network request failed

How can I solve this?

Comment: Try by replacing localhost by your host ip

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I can only speak for Android:
If you are running the emulator localhost (127.0.0.1) will refer to that `10.0.2.2` will refer to your actual localhost.

So in that scenario you would use this:
`http://10.0.2.2:<port>/wordpress/wp-json/wp/v2/posts`

Hope this helps